# Core data - FetchedResultController returning complicated data structures?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

So I have the following structure.Basically a tree view.
Each node has a set (NSSet of nodes), each node is a object that contains an NSDate.

```
-4
-1
   -3
   -2
-5
   -7
   -6
   -8
```

Is it possible to write a Core data query that returns the following result (Each node contains information about it's parent)

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

Items in each level should be sorted by date

Comment: Do you really need to use NSFetchedResultsController, or are you open to other suggestions? What attribute(s) of NSFetchedResultsController do you need?

Comment: I am open to other suggestions. I am happy as long as it performs well in a tree with let's say 400-500 items. I am trying to avoid looping as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NSSortDescriptor... for ex:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
```

More tutorial from this [site](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/).

Comment: I don't see how the sort descriptor would help here other that sorting each level of the tree

Answer (score 0):

Short answer; no.

First, Core Data works with objects not raw values like this.

Second, a `NSFetchedResultsController` is designed to return a set of objects that are of the same entity type and potentially separated into sections.  What you are describing is a multi-level structure and does not fit into the goal of the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

### Update

If you are just looking to get back a `NSArray` of `XEntity` sorted by `yProperty` without regard to the parent/child relationship within `XEntity` then you don't need a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Just create a `NSFetchedRequest` with the `-setEntity:` set to `XEntity` and add a `NSSortDescriptor` that sorts on `yProperty` and execute the fetch against the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

If you want to be updated when that data changes then you would want to use a `NSFetchedResultsController` with that same `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: all my nodes are in the same entity, and they are all the same type. Every object has a parentId which referes to another object in the same entity

Comment: It is still a multi-level structure, even if they are the same entity.  You can build a fetch, etc to retrieve the data and you can build your own watcher to watch for changes but the `NSFetchedResultsController` won't fit.  It is designed for a single level of data.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question completely. I have a tree structure stored in coreData, but I want the fetchedResultController to return a single level of objects, but in the same order as the tree. So if the tree has 20 rows, I want the fetched result controller to return an array with 20 objects. The trick is sorting each item correctly